# SQL group by select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server and I have a table with the following columns:

```
SessionId | Date | first name | last name
```

I would like to do `group by sessionId` and then get the row with the max date.

For example:

```
xxx | 21/12/2012 | f1 | l1
xxx | 20/12/2012 | f2 | l2
yyy | 21/12/2012 | f3 | l3
yyy | 20/12/2012 | f4 | l4
```

I would like to get the following rows:

```
xxx | 21/12/2012 | f1 | l1
yyy | 21/12/2012 | f3 | l3
```

Thank you

Comment: +1 nice simple well laid out question. A further nice feature that is available to enhance sql Q&A is SQLFiddle

Comment: which version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: good to tell us if you are using 2005, 2008R2 or 2012 as the later versions support additional functionality ....you can add this as a tag

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
WITH MAXSessions
AS
(
  SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SessionID ORDER BY Date DESC) rownum
  FROM Sessions
)
SELECT
  SessionId,
  Date,
  firstname,
  lastname 
FROM MAXSessions
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

**Or:**

```
SELECT 
  s.SessionId,
  s.Date,
  s.firstname,
  s.lastname 
FROM Sessions s
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT SessionID, MAX(Date) LatestDate
   FROM sessions
   GROUP BY SessionID
) MAxs  ON maxs.SessionID  = s.SessionID
       AND maxs.LatestDate = s.Date;
```

---

**Update:** To get the count of the sessions, you can do this:

```
SELECT 
  s.SessionId,
  s.Date,
  s.firstname,
  s.lastname,
  maxs.SessionsCount
FROM Sessions s
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT SessionID, COUNT(SessionID), SessionsCount, MAX(Date) LatestDate
   FROM sessions
   GROUP BY SessionID
) MAxs  ON maxs.SessionID  = s.SessionID
       AND maxs.LatestDate = s.Date;
```

Comment: no worries - it was trivial typo but thought better had edit in case OPer was scratching their head.

Comment: (didn't read all your answer ....looks like my answer is identical to your second script)

Comment: ok - managed to get an original script using `EXISTS` into my post in the end!!

Comment: HI, Thanks all, How can I count the sesionsId, regarding the table that i posted i would like to see in the output                            xxx | 21/12/2012 | f1 | l1 |2
yyy | 21/12/2012 | f3 | l3 |2

Comment: add a small sub-query that has `COUNT(SESSIOID)` in it's `SELECT` clause and then join that to any of the examples - `JOINING on SESSIOID`

Comment: @user1941008 Yes like whytheq said. See my edit. Or see his updated answer.

Comment: just amended my EXISTS query to accomodate new request

Answer (score 4):

Here is a live example of Mahmoud's answer - [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/710bc/3)

Here is the same, just using a sub-query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM 
    #Table a
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT 
            SessionID,
            [mx] = MAX([Date])      
        FROM #Table
        GROUP BY SessionID                  
        ) b
        ON
            a.[SessionId ] = b.SessionID AND
            a.[Date] = b.mx;
```

[**HERE IS THE SQL FIDDLE FOR THE ABOVE SUB-QUERY VERSION**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/710bc/5)

You can also use `EXISTS` - this is my favourite:

```
SELECT 
     a.*,
     c.CNT 
FROM 
     #Table a
     INNER JOIN 
        ( --to return a count of sessionIds
        SELECT 
           SessionID,
           [CNT] = COUNT(*)     
        FROM #Table
        GROUP BY SessionID                  
        ) c
          ON a.SessionID = c.SessionID
WHERE 
    EXISTS
        (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #Table b
        WHERE
            a.[SessionId] = b.SessionID AND
            a.[Date] > b.[Date] 
        )
```

[**HERE IS THE SQL FIDDLE WITH THE ADDITIONAL COUNT INCLUDED**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/710bc/7)

Comment: +1 for the SQL fiddle demos and the other way to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options, one would be to use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) that ranks rows by Date:

**Edited to include Session Count**

```
WITH Sessions AS (
    SELECT SessionId, [Date], FirstName, LastName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SessionId ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS Ord
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT S.SessionId, S.Date, S.FirstName, S.LastName, X.SessionCount
FROM Sessions S
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SessionId, COUNT(*) AS SessionCount
    FROM Sessions
    GROUP BY SessionId 
) X ON X.SessionId = S.SessionId  
WHERE S.Ord = 1
```

[Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) are your friend in situations like this, where you want to grab entire rows that meet certain 'ordered' criteria, like max date.

Comment: how can i add the count of sessionId to each row  ?

Comment: Getting the session count as well is a bit more involved, and you should edit your question to include that if you need it.  I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, Simply this will do

```
select a.date1,a.first_name,a.last_name
from(select row_number() 
over(partition by SessionId order by SessionId) rnk,date1,first_name,last_name
from table1) a where a.rnk=1
```

[**SQL_FIDDLE_DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1187/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT b.sessionid, 
       b.date, 
       b.fristname,         b.lastname 
FROM   (SELECT t2.sessionid, 
               Max(t2.date) AS Date 
        FROM   temp1 t2 
        GROUP  BY t2.sessionid) a, 
       temp1 b 
WHERE  a.sessionid = b.sessionid 
       AND a.date = b.date
```

Best way to find result is